# How to paste gnuplot datablocks?

Tags: gnuplot, missing-data

I have to calculate new values within a for loop in gnuplot. How can I paste the results from $Data? I am getting the error message "data block name must be followed by << EODmarker".

```
do for [selected_label in LABELS] {
    set table $Data  
    plot '' index group using ( @sel ):( @corrected_volume ) with table
    unset table
    
    $Temp = $Temp . $Data        
}

print $Temp
```

Comment: This is not a minimal reproduceable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Why the tag `google-maps-markers`? This seems to be a pure gnuplot question. So, basically you want to add a datablock to another datablock?

Comment: @theozh:  Yes, I need to merge multiple blocks of data that I calculate in a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `help table`. You can append to a datablock.

I don't know the details and the dependencies of your script, but check the example below. Hope it helps.
By the way, you could also use

```
set print $Temp append
    print "something"
set print
```

**Script:**

```
### append to an existing datablock
reset session

$Temp <<EOD
 1   4
 2   5
 3   6
EOD

set table $Temp append
    do for [i=1:3] {
        set samples 3
        set xrange [0:2]
        plot '+' u ($1*i):(($1*i)**2) w table
    }
unset table
print $Temp

### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
 1   4
 2   5
 3   6
 0       0
 1       1
 2       4
 0       0
 2       4
 4       16
 0       0
 3       9
 6       36
```

**Addition:**

You can mimic Linux' paste command in gnuplot-only. You index the lines of the datablock (index is 1-based) and remove the last character (which is newline `\n`) and concatenate it with another string and print it to a new datablock. You need to make sure you add not more lines than the original datablock has.

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.2.0, because of indexing of datablocks)

```
### mimic Linux' paste with gnuplot only
reset session

$Temp <<EOD
 1   4
 2   5
 3   6
EOD

set print $Temp2
    do for [j=0:2] {
        tmp_line = ''
        do for [i=1:3] {
            tmp_line = tmp_line.sprintf("  %g  %g", j*i, (j*i)**2)
        }
        print $Temp[j+1][1:strlen($Temp[j+1])-1].tmp_line
    }
set print
print $Temp2
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
 1   4  0  0  0  0  0  0
 2   5  1  1  2  4  3  9
 3   6  2  4  4  16  6  36
```

**Addition 2:**

The following is mimicing Linux' "paste" having a `plot ... w table` in the loop. This get's a bit ugly and requires a third datablock `$Temp3`.
Once you appended `$Temp2` to `$Temp` in `$Temp3` you overwrite `$Temp` with  `$Temp3` and start over for the next iteration. Based on your detailed script this could maybe be simplified.

There are some special things ongoing with the newline character, which I don't fully understand. So, apparently you have to skip the last character of the datablock line, but only for the first time (`i==1`). Furthermore, force the datafile separator to be space when writing to the table, otherwise it would be `TAB`. Mixed column separators are not nice, but gnuplot would also handle this as long as you have `set datafile separator whitespace` which is the default setting.

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.2.0, because of indexing of datablocks)

```
### mimic Linux' paste with gnuplot only
reset session

$Temp <<EOD
 1   4
 2   5
 3   6
EOD

do for [i=1:3] {
    set table $Temp2 separator " "
        set samples 3
        set xrange [0:2]
        plot '+' u ($1*i):(($1*i)**2) w table
    unset table

    set print $Temp3
        do for [j=1:|$Temp2|] {
            print $Temp[j][1:strlen($Temp[j])-(i==1)].$Temp2[j][1:strlen($Temp2[j])]
        }
    set print $Temp
        print $Temp3
    set print
}

print $Temp
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
 1   4 0   0 0   0 0   0
 2   5 1   1 2   4 3   9
 3   6 2   4 4   16 6   36
```

Comment: This looks like the results of "cat" on Linux. Is it possible to mimic "paste" so that all columns are listed side by side?

Comment: @magfan yes, you can. See updated answer.

Comment: This is close. The only problem is still that I have to read the data within a plot command to have access to columns whose values ​​I need for the calculations.

Comment: @magfan well, can also be done... but it get's a bit ugly.

Comment: But it solves my problem and can be extended with many more data blocks.

Comment: @magfan maybe depending on the bigger picture (I don't have your full script), it could also be convenient to work with arrays as another option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253843/discussion-between-magfan-and-theozh).